# Combo box dependent on another

Tags: php, combobox

I want to make it so that when F is chosen the Floor combo box only shows A1 and B1 and when K is selected only A2 and B2 shows.

```
Garage     : <select name="garage">
<option value="F">F</option>
<option value="K">K</option>
</select><br />
Floor      : <select name="floor">
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B1">B1</option>
<option value="A2">A2</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
</select><br />
```

Comment: have you tried searching enough? This is a very common question

Comment: When you say chosen do you mean instantly or upon submission? (javascript vs php)

Comment: When the selection is made instantly. This form was suppose to be made in java (school project), but due to time we couldn't finish the java app leading us to use php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution, reedited, just tested:

```
<script>
function garage_onchange(){
    var selGarageValue = document.getElementById("garage").value;
    var selFloor = document.getElementById("floor");

    for(var i=selFloor.options.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        selFloor.remove(i);
    }

    if(selGarageValue=="F"){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "A1";
        option.value="A1";
        selFloor.add(option);
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "B1";
        option.value="B1";
        selFloor.add(option);
    }
    else if(selGarageValue=="K"){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "A2";
        option.value="A2";
        selFloor.add(option);
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "B2";
        option.value="B2";
        selFloor.add(option);
    }
}
</script>

Garage: 
<select id="garage" name="garage" onchange="garage_onchange();">
<option value="S" selected="selected">-Choose Garage-</option>
<option value="F">F</option>
<option value="K">K</option>
</select>

<br />
Floor: 
<select name="floor" id="floor">
</select>
```

Comment: I'm new to PHP and java, can you explain to me the javascript part? Like do I just put it right under the PHP part or is there something I have to do before hand.

Comment: You need to use javascript, DOM manipulation. That's why you need to put the "id" attribute in each select element, to get them from javascript (document.getElementById("id-element")). Remove all the option items first, then according to the if statement, add the options according to your Original Question.

Comment: Great! I just tested it also and it works, a minor thing though is that at default it is on garage F showing all 4 floors. Is it possible to change this or put "Choose Garage" as the the default selection.

Comment: Yep it works, i just realized i have to do the same concept but when they choose a floor they then have to select a spot. A1 and A2 has spots 101-110, and B1 and B2 has 201-210. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Can you help me adding a spot selection, details above, @ESt3b4n

Comment: Sorry I just realized your comment? If you can, open a new question, so you can explain your case, so I can understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selections to be made instantly, use javascript.

Html:

```
Garage     : <select name="garage" id="garage">
<option value="F">F</option>
<option value="K">K</option>
</select><br />
Floor      : <select name="floor" id="floor">
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B1">B1</option>
</select><br />
```

Javascript:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$("#garage").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "F") {
        $("#floor").html("<option value='A1'>A1</option><option value='B1'>B1</option>");
    } else if (val == "K") {
        $("#floor").html("<option value='A2'>A2</option><option value='B2'>B2</option>");
    }
});

</head>
```

To implement this in your PHP app, just throw the above code in the `<head>` part of your html.